# how to get string from index

Tags: python, string, python-3.6

I wanted to know how do I get string from index.

For example:

- in `user_input` I enter `5 5 4 6 1`
- in `number_pick` I enter `4`
- The correct output should be `Value: 6`

This is my code. It's not giving me the right value. If anyone could help that will be useful. (I'm a beginner in Python)

```
import math 
user_input1 = input("Your chosen number: ")

number_pick = input(" Num?")

value_of_pick1 = user_input1.find(number_pick)

value1 = user_input1[value_of_pick1]

print("Value: ", value1)
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your code?

Comment: for number_pick when i enter 4 .. it doesn't give me the string 6.. but returns the value 4

Comment: you are getting the index and printing the value at the index

Comment: Firstly, which python version are you using, can you provide the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `find()`, you can just parse your `number_pick` to `int`

And I will use `str.split()` method, which simply takes a **string** and *splits* it by a given separator.

```
user_input = input("Your chosen number: ").split(' ')
# I use .split(' ') to make '5 4 4 6 1' into ['5', '4', '4', '6', '1']
# Because now it will be easier to index it

number_pick = int(input("Num: "))
# If we enter 4, this will be the integer 4, not '4'

# And now we just take the element with our index - 1,
# because lists are zero-indexed
value = user_input[number_pick - 1]

print("Value: {}".format(value))  # Value: 6
```

And after running this code:

```
>>> Your chosen number: 5 5 4 6 1
['5', '4', '4', '6', '1']
>>> Num: 4
4

Value: 6
```

And I think `math` is redundant for this piece of code.

#### `split()` usage explanation:

When we enter `5 4 4 6 1` for our `user_input` variable, it's value is simply the string `"5 4 4 6 1"`.

When we do `.split(' ')` on it, it creates a list with our values, separated by `" "`.

So after doing split, we have `['5', '4', '4', '6', '1']`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for more information.

Comment: i still haven't learn split method.. but by using this it does give the string.. thank you

Comment: @Dipte I edited my answer with some explanation about the `str.split()` method.

Comment: @dipte If it helped you make sure to upvote. And have a nice day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in lists indexing begins at 0 not 1. So this should give you the wanted result:

```
value_of_pick1 = user_input1.find(number_pick - 1)
```

Comment: it's showing error if i put ..value_of_pick1 = user_input1.find(number_pick - 1) ... is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user_input1 = input("Your chosen number: ").split()
number_pick = input(" Num?")
print("Value: ", user_input1[int(number_pick)-1]) #index starts at 0
```

Comment: it's giving the index not string ..but thanks for your effort

Comment: Edited.I think u want the fourth number from the list

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the nature of the `find` option in `string` and the idea that it returns an index, with a `list`.
`find` determines if string str occurs in string and returns its `index` which is the starting point of `str` within the `string`
So:

```
>>> a="now is the winter"
>>> a.find("winter")
11
```

The word "winter" exists in a and starts at position 11 (starting from position zero)
In your case:

```
>>> a="5 5 4 6 1"
>>> a.find("4")
4
```

is the correct answer.

Extending this out, you can manipulate the results of the index from `find`

```
>>> a="now is the winter of our discontent, made glorious Summer by this Son of York"
>>> f="winter"
>>> x = a.find(f)
>>> a[x:]
'winter of our discontent, made glorious Summer by this Son of York'
>>> a[x:len(f)+x]
'winter'
```

Best run with the answer that converts it to a list, as that appears to be what you actually wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing by using this code instead of using **Find**.

```
user_input1 = input("Your chosen number: ").split() 
#spliting input into list

number_pick = int(input(" Num?")) 
#explicitly converting into integer

user_input1_tolist = [int(i) for i in user_input1] 
#using list comprehension to convert into list

value1 = user_input1_tolist[number_pick] 
#index starting from zero

print("Value: ", value1)
```